# How to solve bosh API version issue?

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant, cloud-foundry, cf-bosh, bosh-deployer

I have deployed cloud foundry in my local machine.I am able to set the target and able to deploy services.I have followed the following link to deploy services https://github.com/cloudfoundry-community/cf-services-contrib-release .But when I am trying to create service I am facing the following issue :

```
    cf create-service-auth-token mongodb core mytoken
    FAILED
    create-service-auth-token only works up to CF API version 2.46.0. Your target is 2.51.0.
```

Comment: This is not a BOSH issue, it's a CF issue.  You're trying to issue a deprecated command that isn't supported by the CF API you're targetting.  Why do you want to `create-service-auth-token`?  Don't you just want to `create-service`?

Comment: sorry I am very new to cloud foundry I was just following the instruction from this link https://github.com/cloudfoundry-community/cf-services-contrib-release .In this tutorial it was metioned to use this command .I will try to create-services. thanks!!